# How to open Firefox about:reader?url=example.com with Intent on Android

Tags: android, android-intent, uri

I'm a trying to open a webpage on an android application, the url sheme is a bit special it has to open an url in reader mode : **`about:reader?url=example.com`**

I am doing it this way

```
Uri intentUri = new Uri.Builder().encodedPath("about:reader")
    .appendQueryParameter("url", Uri.encode("example.com"))
    .build();

// Try to open in Firefox If available or use default
Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(intentUri);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.setPackage("org.mozilla.firefox");

try {
    getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
    intent.setPackage(null);
    getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
}
```

Logcat:

`E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=about:reader?url=http://example.com`

Is there a way to achieve this ?

Answer (score -1):

**Try this**

```
final String pdf_url = "http://example.com"; // DON'T forget http{s}:// prefix.
// Try to open in Firefox If available or use default
Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(pdf_url));
// You can also using Google viewer 
// intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse( "http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=" + pdf_url), "text/html");
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.setPackage("org.mozilla.firefox");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this does not differ from my code.
Also the url needs to be ```about:reader?url=http://example.com```
the problem is the ```about:reader``` part that is not handled correctly I think.